# android how change size image in background xml

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I'm making a layer-list for drawable...
I would like set stroke (2dp, color: #000000), corners (5dp), background (yellow) and add image on the right side, but i can't change image size.

What i want:
[image: What i want]

but i have something like that:

[image: wrong effect]

this is my code:
content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="info.e_konkursy.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_tablerow11"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:text="@string/country"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="Poland"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

bg_tablerow11.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <item>
        <shape
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I can see you copied the same xml twice.
'bg_tablerow11.xml'  same as 'content_main.xml

Comment: I am so sorry, my mistake, now it is okay.

Comment: The country name can be changed. Default is view only text "Country:" and image in background. I implement setOnClickListener and then added country name

Comment: why not put an imageview in the table layout ? then add the background border without an image to the relative layout

Comment: O yeah. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.J. thanks for help :)

Answer:
content_main.xml:

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="50dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/bg_tablerow">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView2"
>         android:layout_width="100dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:text="@string/country"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView3"
>         android:layout_width="150dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
>         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
>         android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
>         android:gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:text="Poland"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView2"
>         android:layout_width="30dp"
>         android:layout_height="30dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
>         android:background="@drawable/arrow"
>         android:scaleType="fitXY" />
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

bg_tablerow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFEE00" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#eeaaff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Welcome Pionas :)